# Lilypond - autochange with alternative staves / turning point

Tags: lilypond

I want a single voice drifting across two staves, and I want LilyPond to automatically decide which staff to use.

(As can be seen [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-keyboards.en.html#changing-staff-automatically)) For treble and bass clefs this is easily implemented with the `\autochange` command:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\new PianoStaff 
<<
    \new Staff = "up" {
        \clef "treble"
        \autochange {
            c,4 e, g, b, |
            d f a c' |
            e' g' b' d''|
        }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
        \clef "bass"
    }
>>
```

[image: autochange]

---

But (as I'm transcribing guitar), I want to use suboctave clefs (`treble_8` and `bass_8`).

When I try this ... :

```
\version "2.18.2"
\new PianoStaff 
<<
    \new Staff = "up" {
        \clef "treble_8"
        \autochange {
            c,4 e, g, b, |
            d f a c' |
            e' g' b' d''|
        }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
        \clef "bass_8"
    }
>>
```

[image: autochange - suboctave]

... LilyPond is still assuming that the turning point is at middle c (`c'`), and not at the appropriate c below middle c (`c`):

---

I know I could just change staff manually.  But
*is there a way to get LilyPond to use the `\autochange` command correctly with the alternative staffs or with an alternative turning point?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you insist on using version 2.18? 2.19 can do it without trouble. You just have to stick the turning point just after the `\autochange`. So instead of `\autochange { music }`, you would use `\autochange c { music }`. This is what my Lilypond 2.19.62 does when I do that with your example (otherwise copied verbatim):

```
\version "2.19.62"
\language "german"

\new PianoStaff 
<<
    \new Staff = "up" {
        \clef "treble_8"
        \autochange c {
            c,4 e, g, b, |
            d f a c' |
            e' g' b' d''|
        }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
        \clef "bass_8"
    }
>>
```

[image]

(It looks a bit different because I use different fonts, and the B's come out as B flats because I use `\language "german"`. But otherwise it's all good.)

(Also don't let yourself to be put off by the fact that 2.19's are the "development" version. They're in fact very stable. I use it a lot and during those couple of years, it has crashed on me only once.)

Comment: I found version 2.19.83, installed it and now it works !  Thank you

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Good! Glad that worked. Also there are more new things in 2.19 — one of my most favorite is probably copying the last note with different rhythm (`c4 8 16 16~ 16 16 8` is the same as `c4 c8 c16 c16~ c16 c16 c8`). You could like to look here: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/changes/index.html .